# how to restore HTML elements that are removed by jQuery's remove

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#remove').click(function()
    {
        $('.test').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-wraper">
    <div class="test">
        test
    </div>
    <div class="test2">
        test2
    </div>
</div>
<button id='remove'>Remove</button>
<button id='back'>Back</button>
```

I want to restore my `.test` div using jQuery, after I've removed it. How do I achieve this?

Comment: When you remove it, it's gone. Why not just move it somewhere else and hide it?

Comment: use show hide instead of removing it.

Comment: or save it to a variable before you remove it: var $test = $('.test');

Comment: if you need it gone from DOM use `detach()` and save a reference, else use hide and show like @TimSpeckhals as shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a variable and before removing it store the dom in it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var cacheDom = "";
  $('#remove').click(function(){
        cacheDom = $('.test'); //storing the value in dom
    $('.test').remove();
  });
 $('#add').click(function(){
        $('.test3').append(cacheDom); // appending it back
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var cacheDom = "";
  $('#remove').click(function(){
   if ($('.test').length > 0) {
          cacheDom = $('.test');
          $('.test').remove();
        }
  });
 $('#add').click(function(){
  $('.test3').append(cacheDom);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-wraper">
<div class="test">
test
</div>
<div class="test2">
test2
</div>
</div>
<div class="test3"></div>
<button id='remove'>Remove</button>
<button id='add'>Add Back</button>
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/cnjgm21b/)

Comment: use detach() and have it in one line instead of two to remove, also if your remove is clicked twice it loses the reference.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for `.hide();` and `.show();`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#remove').click(function(){
    $('.test').hide();
  });
  $('#back').click(function(){
    $('.test').show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test-wraper">
<div class="test">
test
</div>
<div class="test2">
test2
</div>
</div>
<button id='remove'>Remove</button>
<button id='back'>Back</button>
```

Comment: i have to remove  not to hide and show but thanks for help

Comment: @Rohit Why do you need to remove it?

Comment: its causing prob. on scrolling my page and hide show not working on there after removing its scroll smoothly

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you cannot restore any HTML tags that are removed by jquery function. Instead, to remove the elements without removing data and events you can use .detach() function.

Comment: *...function, if you do not have a reference stored to those DOM nodes. Instead...*